# Can't get gradle Dependencies to work

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gradle, libgdx

Gradle/libgdx/Eclipse

Following Project Structure:

```
MainProject
    -build.gradle
    -settings.gradle
LibraryProject
    -build.gradle
    -settings.gradle
```

I can't seem to declare the dependency to the library correctly.

MainProject build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':LibraryProject')
}
```

MainProject settings.gradle

```
include ':LibraryProject'
project(':LibraryProject').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../LibraryProject')
```

Refreshing dependencies works without error. But I can't access any library classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible (in almost all cases) to reliably include a root project as a subproject of another multi-project build. You should not share subprojects between different Gradle builds.

There are two ways to solve this:

- Change the dependency on `:LibraryProject` to a normal dependency: `YourGroup:LibraryProject:1.0-SNAPSHOT`. When you make changes to the library project, you first have to manually build the library project, and install it in a (local) repository. Then you can build the main project.
- Make the library project an actual subproject of the main project.

What is best depends on the purpose of the library project. Is it a project to be reused by multiple applications? Then use the first approach. If it is specifically for the main project, then a subproject is better.